# Initializing a c++ string with argv

Tags: c++, string, argv

I have a function that takes a c++ style string. I want to either put `argv[1]` into a c++ string, or simply pass it directly to my function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string  rev (string &reverse);

int main(int argc, char argv[])
{
if (argc != 2)
    cout << "Bad Input" << endl;
string reverse = argv[1];
cout << rev(reverse) << endl;   
}
```

This is what I have so far, but when I do this, I get the following error:

```
8.4.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char*)’:
8.4.cpp:11: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’
8.4.cpp:11: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’
```

Comment: use `char * argv[]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fix main

```
int main(int argc, char argv[])

// should be

int main(int argc, char  *    argv[]) 
        ///            ^^^^^
```

Comment: It's exactly the same but I prefer this syntax : 
`int main(int argc, char** argv)`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned `argv[]` is a pointer, to a block of memory, or a "pointer to a pointer".
You simply need to add `*` to `argv[]` to make it act such.

A quick Google brought up [THIS](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson14.html)

Comment: +1 Yes, it is a pointer to a pointer. *argv[] is the same as **argv. It cannot be used as a pointer to an array, (IE this is not usable (*argv)[0]). Though it can be viewed both ways (pointer to pointer, pointer to array). Since an array is just a pointer.

Comment: Ah, not quite... It is a block of memory which degenerates into a pointer at its first opportunity. Subtlely different...

Comment: Hmm... I never viewed it that way +1 again! :) Though the important part is just knowing how to use it (well I think so anyways)!

Comment: Hmm so is it a pointer to a pointer that can be treated as an array of pointers? That is what I read once... Hmm (I never really questioned how it works before)...

Comment: Sorry I would edit my comment (but I cannot), what I meant to say was "array of pointers", not "pointer to array"... Oops.